# How to Analyse Failed Request Tracing log for IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, trace

there is a error in my IIS7 on one website so i [activate the Failed Request Tracing log](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/) and get some XML files, how to analyze this XML stuff? Any tools outside?

I found [FRT Logs Article](http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2008/10/30/debug-and-troubleshoot-rewrite-rules-easily.aspx) but is there any comfortable LogSuite available to analyze all FRT Logs in a directory?

Comment: not tool anyways ?

Answer (score 15):

I know this is old but in case anyone comes across this like I did, IE loads it up with all the pretty formatting, tabs, and collapsible sections as shown in https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/iis-7-troubleshooting

Which doesn't exactly answer, as it I wouldn't call it a tool but it appears to be the intended way to view it, while not readily apparent [at least in my opinion given that many of the logs output by Microsoft nowadays have viewers to parse the data]

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning, if you do this on a server with Internet Explorer Enhanced Security enabled you'll need to add an exception if prompted, otherwise you just see a big block of xml